# Find the angle made by the intersection point and midpoints of the diagonals of a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, let $AD$ and $CB$ meet at $P$. Let $E$ and $F$ be the midpoints of $DB$ and $CA$ respectively. Find $\angle PEF$ in terms of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$, which are the angles of the cyclic quadrilateral.

[image]

Comment: If the circle rotates, then the angles at $A,B,C,D$ stay constant. but it seems the angle $PEF$ will vary.

Comment: @coffeemath what do you mean by "If the circle rotates"? It seems that once you have a cyclic quadrilateral, all of the above is fixed?

Comment: Plato-- I guess my comment is not right, but maybe I was trying to express the ambiguity in definition of angle PEF noted in Artino's example below.

Answer (score 2):

Angle $\angle PEF$, in general, does not depend only on the angles of the cyclic quadrilateral. See below an example, with two cyclic quadrilaterals having the same angles (they have parallel sides) but different values for $\angle PEF$. You also need to know the radius of the circle.

[image]

EDIT.

The radius of the circle is not enough: it is clear that one can scale the second figure so as to make two equal circles while keeping the same angles.

Comment: What do you think is enough to know?

Comment: One example could be knowing the eight angles, pairwise equal, formed by the diagonals with the sides.

Comment: Is it easy to calculate it from that?

Comment: I don't know. My guess is that such a formula would be very complicated, but I could be wrong of course.